# Projections in Mongodb not working properly

Tags: mongodb, go

I have this data in my mongoDB database.

```
{ 
   "_id":"5d9ce9fd270eae22adb95d70",
   ...
   "isdriver":true,
   "driver":{ 
      "walletmoney":0,
      "license":"6eef8271-62d7-4a1c-972a-2c40a773b35a",
      "vehicle":{ 
         "image":"b6c3619b-86e6-49d0-8734-e2c48815dfc1",
         "insurance":"5f8229c4-4700-4059-8b72-9344a2bc6092",
         "manufacturer":"Tesla",
         "model":"Model 3",
         "vin":"12345678912345678",
         "year":2018
      },
      "verified":false
      ...
   }
}
```

Here is my driver struct

```
type Driver struct {
    ...
    Verified         bool    `json:"verified,omitempty"`
    License          string  `json:"licenseimage,omitempty"`
    ...
    Vehicle          Vehicle `json:"vehicle,omitempty"`
}
```

Here is my Student Struct

```
type Student struct {
    ID                primitive.ObjectID `bson:"_id,omitempty"`
    ...
    IsDriver          bool               `json:"isdriver,omitempty"`
    Driver            Driver             `json:"driver,omitempty"`
}
```

Vehicle struct

```
type Vehicle struct {
    Image        string `json:"vehicleimage,omitempty"`
    Insurance    string `json:"insuranceimage,omitempty"`
    VIN          string `json:"vin,omitempty"`
    Manufacturer string `json:"manufacturer,omitemptyr"` <-----(Edit) Find out this is also wrong
    Model        string `json:"model,omitempty"`
    Year         uint16 `json:"year,omitempty"`
}
```

And I'm using this function to get all the drivers from the database

```
func GetAllDrivers() []model.Driver {

    // Options
    projections := bson.D{
        {"driver", 1},
        /* {"driver.verified", 1},
        {"driver.license", 1}, */
    }

    // Filter for search
    filter := bson.M{"isdriver": true}

    // Return student collection (*mongo.Collection)
    studentCollection := GetStudentCollection()
    cur, err := studentCollection.Find(context.TODO(), filter, options.Find().SetProjection(projections))

    // Error while finding documents
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Print(err)
        return []model.Driver{}
    }

    var drivers []model.Driver
    var driver model.Driver

    // Get the next result from the cursor
    for cur.Next(context.TODO()) {
        err := cur.Decode(&driver)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Print(err)
        }
        drivers = append(drivers, driver)
    }
    if err := cur.Err(); err != nil {
        fmt.Print(err)
    }
    cur.Close(context.TODO())
    return drivers
}
```

But the response I'm getting in the postman is ridiculous

```
[
    {
        "vehicle": {
            "manufacturer": ""
        }
    },
    {
        "vehicle": {
            "manufacturer": ""
        }
    }
]
```

One thing is okay that is in response I'm getting two objects which are fine because as my `filter` suggestest `isdriver: true` I have total three documents in the database in which two of those have `isdriver: true`.

Can anybody help me with this? Why I'm getting this response?

Comment: Most likely, because fields in `model.Driver` are unexported. And I somehow doubt that a DBMS made the concious choice to ridicule you...

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg all fields have first letter capital.

Comment: Have you read the link I sent you? `GetStudentCollection()`? `Vehicle`? I am not sure how you feel, but if I have to reverse-engineer the code to be able to answer the question, I feel less inclined to put time and effort into it...

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg I have posted the remaining things.  I think I posted enough things so you can reproduce the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing a find in the students collection, but you decode into a driver.
This needs to be changed.

```golang
    var drivers []Driver
    var student Student

    // Get the next result from the cursor
    for cur.Next(context.TODO()) {
        err := cur.Decode(&student)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
        drivers = append(drivers, student.Driver)
    }
```

Furthermore , you are lacking an `Inline` struct tag for the `Driver` field of `Student`:

```golang
type Student struct {
    ID       primitive.ObjectID `bson:"_id,omitempty"`
    IsDriver bool               `json:"isdriver,omitempty"`
    // Note that Inline is uppercase.
    Driver   Driver             `json:"driver,omitempty" bson:"driver,Inline"`
}
```

Same, of course, goes for all referenced structs. Working sample code: https://gist.github.com/mwmahlberg/c46ec3ad3ccee028f0666ff7d5d8d98b

Comment: What `Inline` does? And yes I'm aware of the I'm decoding into a driver I thought I don't need to decode into student because I'm getting only driver part.

Comment: `@VarunRaj https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson/bsoncodec#StructTags